# Interact with the Nicks Pallet [not displayed in combo - Pallet Interactor]

Tags: substrate

Checked that the new dependencies is running correctly - run cargo and a temporary node in development mode in [node-template].

When I start yarn [Front-End Template] 'Nicks' is not displayed in combo 'Pallet Interactor'..

Checked cargo.toml/lib.rs to ensure that I have followed tutorial, and can not see where I am going wrong.

I would appreciate some advice on where I am going wrong, and how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you have completed everything through the "Configure the Nicks Pallet" section, the dispatchable calls from the Nicks pallet should be visible in the Pallet Interactor component. Can you please stop both the node and the front-end, ensure that you have the node compiled, and restart everything?

Comment: I have configured [runtime/src/lib.rs] for the Nicks pallet as described in tutorial - (parameter_types! - construct_runtime!).
Stop both nodes (node-template/front-end-template) and restart everything...
Still not able to see 'nicks' in combo 'Pallet Interactor'
Have careful gone over several times to check what I’ve done, although still can’t workout what I am actually doing wrong?
Appreciate any advice ion this issue..

Comment: Did you compile the node by running `cargo build` after you added the Nicks pallet?

Comment: Yes, I use cargo build. I now receive errors and the build fails ; error type annotations needed. it obvious I am doing something wrong..

Comment: No, you are on the right track! There is a bug in the current Rust nightly unfortunately. Can you try adding [this patch](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/pull/92/files)? You need to specify the nightly to use and you can do that by adding a `rust-toolchain` file with that contents.

Comment: I run rustup install nightly-2020-10-06 'patch' in folder substrate-node-template, and cargo build in same folder - then run a temporary node in development mode.....

Comment: In folder substrate-first-end-template, run yarn start... I am still getting the same issue - Nicks pallet is not visible in Pallet Interactor....

Comment: I will continue to research this, and I appreciate your comments and support! Could my issue be due to not configuring ‘pallets_template_src_lib.rs and runtime_src_lib.rs’ correctly?

Comment: Here are more detailed steps for how to use the 2020-10-06 nightly. https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/90#issuecomment-706041447

Comment: Hi followed example (link above).. had to also update 'rustup toolchain install nightly'..  Check the new dependencies is running correctly..Got error - failed to read `C_Users_utils_wasm_builder_Cargo.toml`......

Comment: If this due to I am running on Windows 10 platform or is it due to mapping C drive ... my files are store in C_dev (folder)?

Comment: error code received: (exit code:1)...